# Spring Transaction Blocks On Hibernate Query Execution

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-transactions

I am using spring boot 2.0 and hibernate version 4.3.5. I have written a junit test case that gets blocked on a hibernate query execution. The service implementation is as below

```
@Override
@Transactional
public void deleteAllEmployeesForDept(Long dptId) {
    entityManager.createQuery("DELETE FROM " + Person.class.getName() +
            " WHERE dptId=:dptId").setParameter("dptId", dptId).
            executeUpdate();
}
```

Below is the test class -

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
public class PersonServiceTest extends TestSupport {

@Autowired
private PersonService personService;

    @Before
    public void init() {
        Person p = createPerson();

        personService.save(p);

    }


    @Test
    public void testDelete() {
        personService.deleteAllEmployeesForDept(1l);
    }

}
```

The spring beans xml is defined as below

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" proxy-target-class="true"/>

    <bean id="personService"
              class="com.mypackage.service.definition.PersonServiceImpl"/>

    <bean id="entityBasePackages" class="java.lang.String">
        <constructor-arg value="com.mypackage"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

We use the JPATransactionManager. 
The delete test case hangs. On enabling transaction logs for package (org.springframework.orm.jpa) I see that beforeCommit synchronization is not getting executed. Any thoughts on what could be wrong?

```
09:15:14.253 DEBUG [main][o.s.o.jpa.JpaTransactionManager] Creating new transaction with name [com.mypackage.service.definition.PersonServiceImpl.save]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT
09:15:14.254 DEBUG [main][o.s.o.jpa.JpaTransactionManager] Opened new EntityManager [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl@421d54b3] for JPA transaction
09:15:14.254 DEBUG [main][o.s.o.jpa.JpaTransactionManager] Exposing JPA transaction as JDBC [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect$HibernateConnectionHandle@63f40ca0]
09:15:14.268 TRACE [main][o.s.o.jpa.JpaTransactionManager] Triggering beforeCommit synchronization
09:15:14.268 TRACE [main][o.s.o.jpa.JpaTransactionManager] Triggering beforeCompletion synchronization
09:15:14.268 DEBUG [main][o.s.o.jpa.JpaTransactionManager] Initiating transaction commit
09:15:14.268 DEBUG [main][o.s.o.jpa.JpaTransactionManager] Committing JPA transaction on EntityManager [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl@421d54b3]
09:15:14.271 TRACE [main][o.s.o.jpa.JpaTransactionManager] Triggering afterCommit synchronization
09:15:14.271 TRACE [main][o.s.o.jpa.JpaTransactionManager] Triggering afterCompletion synchronization
09:15:14.271 DEBUG [main][o.s.o.jpa.JpaTransactionManager] Closing JPA EntityManager [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl@421d54b3] after transaction
09:15:14.271 DEBUG [main][.s.o.j.EntityManagerFactoryUtils] Closing JPA EntityManager
09:15:14.271 DEBUG [main][o.s.o.jpa.JpaTransactionManager] Creating new transaction with name [com.mypackage.service.definition.PersonServiceImpl.deleteAllEmployeesForDept]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT
09:15:14.271 DEBUG [main][o.s.o.jpa.JpaTransactionManager] Opened new EntityManager [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl@20d19f2c] for JPA transaction
09:15:14.272 DEBUG [main][o.s.o.jpa.JpaTransactionManager] Exposing JPA transaction as JDBC [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect$HibernateConnectionHandle@45592af7]
```